# Getting data by compering two dataframes

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have stumbled upon a hard question for me newbie experience with Pandas.
I have a problem joining two excel files that look like this way:

| id | name | language | gr_id | show |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Peter | en | 1 |  |
| 2 | Petrus | latin | 1 | 1 |
| 3 | Peter | de | 1 |  |
| 4 | Victor | en | 2 |  |
| 5 | Victor | latin | 2 | 1 |
| 6 | Claudius | latin | 3 | 1 |
| 7 | Claudio | spanish | 3 |  |

Now in another excel, I have this:

| name | original_version_of_name |
| --- | --- |
| Peter |  |
| Victor |  |
| Claudio |  |

What I want is to have the original_version_of_name filled with Latin version of the name, so the second excel looks like this:

| name | original_version_of_name |
| --- | --- |
| Peter | Petrus |
| Victor | Victor |
| Claudio | Claudius |

I have been trying to come up with something like merging, but it is not giving me the right results.

```
df_merge = pd.merge(df1, df2, how='left', left_on='name', right_on='name')

#I have also tried this, but it does not work
df['original_version_of_name'] = [df2['name'] if df2['language'] == 'latin' else 'null' for df2['name'] in df['name']]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Main tool is boolean indexing:

```py
def get_latin(name):
    # Get the name `gr_id`
    gr_id = df2.loc[df2['name'] == name, 'gr_id'].tolist()

    # Select by gr_id
    gr_id_mask = df2['gr_id'].isin(gr_id)

    # Select rows in group where language is latin 
    latin_mask = df2.loc[gr_id_mask, 'language'] == 'latin'

    # Select the names where language is latin 
    latin_names = df2.loc[gr_id_mask & latin_mask, 'name'].tolist()

    return latin_names[0] if len(latin_names) else ''

df['original_version_of_name'] = df['name'].apply(get_latin)
```

```py
      name original_version_of_name
0    Peter                   Petrus
1   Victor                   Victor
2  Claudio                 Claudius
```